# Linux pthread portability on windows

Tags: windows, linux, pthreads

For a certain project,I have to use the static mutex initializer in pthread.However my library is supposed to be portable on Windows as well.

```
pthread_mutex_t csapi_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Is there a corrosponding static initializer on windows.?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.

Comment: does this mean the same code will work on windows?

Comment: if you are going to use pthreads on windows, yes. But to use pthreads on windows you need Cygwin

Comment: No.I am planning to use it on a native windows system.I want to know if there is a corrosponding static initializer available in windows native systems.

Comment: if you are planning on using native stuff, you can't use pthreads, because pthreads isn't native. You would have to use window's mutexes, and they are not a `pthread_mutex_t`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run pthreads on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542286/how-to-run-pthreads-on-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do static initialization of mutexes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555859/is-it-possible-to-do-static-initialization-of-mutexes-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this port of pthread-compatible mutex operations:

```
#define MUTEX_TYPE             HANDLE
#define MUTEX_INITIALIZER      NULL
#define MUTEX_SETUP(x)         (x) = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL)
#define MUTEX_CLEANUP(x)       (CloseHandle(x) == 0)
#define MUTEX_LOCK(x)          emulate_pthread_mutex_lock(&(x))
#define MUTEX_UNLOCK(x)        (ReleaseMutex(x) == 0)

int emulate_pthread_mutex_lock(volatile MUTEX_TYPE *mx)
{ if (*mx == NULL) /* static initializer? */
  { HANDLE p = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if (InterlockedCompareExchangePointer((PVOID*)mx, (PVOID)p, NULL) != NULL)
      CloseHandle(p);
  }
  return WaitForSingleObject(*mx, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED;
}
```

Basically, you want the initialization to happen atomically when the lock is used the first time. If two threads enter the if-body, then only one succeeds in initializing the lock. Note that there is no need to CloseHandle() for the static lock's lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

[Pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) should provide very good support for such constructs.  But I have not checked.