# Error using pthread on Windows with Mingw

Tags: c, pthreads, mingw

I'm trying to use threads on a Windows C program, compiled on an Eclipse environment and Mingw.

I've also put -lpthread and -pthread on the compilation command, and included  on the program.

I made calls to pthread_create(), pthread_cancel() and pthread_exit() where appropriate on my logic.

It always works as intended, but that my program ends saying

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way.
>       Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Any hints? Am I missing something?

**Update**

Global variable:

```
pthread_t thr;
```

Inside the start function:

```
pthread_create(&thr,NULL,ThrFunc,NULL);
pthread_join(thr,NULL);
```

Inside *ThrFunc*:

```
while (TRUE)
{
    // do something
    if (some other thing occurs)
       pthread_exit();
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Maybe you're releasing the resources of the pthread before it returns from its start function?

Comment: "*calls to `pthread_cancel()`*" make me feel uncomfortable ...

Comment: Whatever you have shown so far looks fine. What's that *start* function? Is it the main() function of your application? Can you include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @BlueMoon In fact, this code is contained on a DLL. The start function is a function exported from this DLL and called by the main() function of the application.

Comment: That's fine. But my previous comments' questions still stand. It's not possible to tell *why* you get that message with whatever you have shown so far.

Comment: No way to get a quick mcve. It's interesting that commenting all pthread commands on the source and compiling, the program obviously does not do what I want, but the error message remains. It only dissapears when I also take off -lpthread from the compiling command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run pthreads on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542286/how-to-run-pthreads-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

AFAIK there is no portable pthread library for Windows under Mingw.

I solved my problem using CreateThread(), and let Mingw resolves it using Windows native threads.

Answer (score 1):

> "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information."

To solve this have look on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/884538).

Or

When `abort()` function is getting called from your application you will see that error.

[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx)

> abort
>
> Aborts the current process and returns an error code.
>
> void abort( void ); Return Value
>
> abort does not return control to the calling process. By default, it
>   terminates the current process and returns an exit code of 3.
>
> Remarks
>
> By default, the abort routine prints the message:
>
> "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information."

But in your case you need to find why `abort()` is getting called .